# Pandas Change Index Pro's & Con's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to make hundreds of dataframes, and index them all starting at 1 as opposed to 0. I have found three functional approaches, but I'm not certain if there is a optimal/preferable approach. Can anyone give me insight if there are any pros and cons of the following options?:

```
 df.index += 1

 df.index = df.index + 1

 df.index = range(1,len(df)+1)
```

Comment: Pros: you'll make mathematicians happy.  Cons: You'll make developers unhappy.

Comment: I think it's probably splitting hairs between the first two. `df.index += 1` _may_ work in-place, I'm not sure if there are separate rules for the index. I wouldn't use the 3rd

Comment: For hundreds of dataframes with index starting from 1, personally I would set  index = range(1,len(data)+1) in DataFrame call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `df.index + 1`

This assumes `df.index` are actually integers of the appropriate sort.  I don't like it.  It will fail if not integer like.  Or not fail but not guarantee that you accomplish your goal.

#### `pd.RangeIndex`

Make no assumptions and get on with your life.  This will do what you want, every time!

```
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df) + 1)
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you!